# Ошибка при выполнении SQL-запроса

Tags: mysql

Помогите, при выполнении нижепредставленного кода выдаёт ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to
> your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near '' at line 1.

Что это значит?

```
<?  require_once '/../login.php';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Невозможно подключится к MySQL: ". mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database)
or die("Невозможно выбрать базу данных: " . mysql_error());

$number = `{$_POST[Uid]}`;
$query = "UPDATE  `users`.`resuyms` SET  `Dolgnost` =  '
{$_POST[Dolgnost]}' WHERE  `resuyms`.`Uid` ={$number} ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Сбой при отправке данных. Повторите попытку позже." . mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расширение mysql устарело. Используйте mysqli или PDO.

Данный код уязвим для SQL-injection. Для экранирования для расширения mysql используйте функцию mysql_real_escape_string();

Зачем использовать фигурные скобки "$number = {$_POST[Uid]};"?

Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
$number = intval($_POST['Uid']); 
$jobPosition = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Dolgnost']);
$query = "UPDATE  users.resuyms SET  Dolgnost = '$jobPosition' WHERE  resuyms.Uid =$number"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
if (!$result) die ("Сбой при отправке данных. Повторите попытку позже." . mysql_error());
```